# C# cant implement interface method because of different signatures (using generics)

Tags: c#, generics, inner-classes

I have one basic class with two nested classes. One of that nested class is implementing an Interface where i have a method signature with the return type of a nested object.

This is what i got:

**Class A**

```
using System;

namespace Nested
{
    class A
    {
        public class Item
        {
            //Implementation 
        }

        class B : IInterface
        {
            //
            public Item Get()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Interface for Class A**

```
namespace Nested
{
    internal interface IInterface
    {
        A.Item Get();
    }
}
```

---

Same with generics

**Class B**

```
using System;


namespace Nested
{
    class A<T>
    {
        public class Item<T>
        {
            //Implementation 
        }

        class B<T> : IInterface<T>
        {
            //
            public Item<T> Get()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Interface for class B**

```
namespace Nested
{
    internal interface IInterface<T>
    {
        A<T>.Item<T> Get();
    }
}
```

The first code, that isnt using generics, is just working fine. Compared to that, the example with the generics is giving me the following error:

```
Class1.cs(13,22): error CS0738: 'A<T>.B<T>' does not implement interface member 'IInterface<T>.Get()'. 'A<T>.B<T>.Get()' cannot implement 'IInterface<T>.Get()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'A<T>.Item<T>
```

Why does it say, that the return types are different when the interface uses `A<T>.Item<T> Get();` and the class `public Item<T> Get()` ? Any ideas?

**Edit: Stop formatting the error code to a blockquote, because pieces are getting lost. Thats not the correct message i got.**

Comment: because `A.Item` and `A.Item<T>` are different types and your interface contract is to return `Item` from `Get` method not `Item<T>`

Comment: The interface says, that it has to return A<T>.Item<T> Get();

Comment: You got a warning that explained what the problem was. **Pay attention to compiler warnings and understand them before you ask questions here.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have

```cs
class A<T>
{
    class B<T> { }
}
```

you should (depending on your settings) get a [compiler warning CS0693](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0693):

> Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'A'

This is because a nested class inside a generic class will pick up the type argument of the outer class, e.g.

```
class A<T>
{
   class B
   {
       public T Value { get; set; }
   {
}
```

is perfectly valid - `B` gets the same type parameters as its outer class `A` so can use it as if it were defined as a non-nested class `B<T>`.

Your code is equivalent to

```
class A<T>
{
    class B<U> { }
}
```

or, in other words, the type parameters in `A` and `B` are different and you have no hope of satisfying the interface.

If you ignore that warning (not recommended) can do some horrible stuff like this:

```
#pragma warning disable 0693

public class A<T> where T : struct
{
    public class B<T> where T : class
    {
    }
}

#pragma warning restore 0693
```

which would have no hope of compiling if the `T` in `A<T>` and `B<T>` were the same type parameter (a type can't be both a `struct` and a `class`), but instead is just very confusing.

If viewed in Visual Studio, the IntelliSense will show this:

[image: Nested generic classes with IntelliSense]

so the `T` in the scope of `A<T>` is **not** the same as the `T` in the scope of `B<T>` - the latter *hides* the former.

In fact, there's nothing to stop you from having

```
var ab = new A<double>.B<Object>();
```

even though the *name* of the type parameters is `T` for both `A<T>` and `B<T>`. Hence the compiler warning.

---

I think what you want is this:

```
class A<T>
{
    public class Item
    {
        //Implementation 
    }

    class B : IInterface<T>
    {
        public Item Get()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

internal interface IInterface<T>
{
    A<T>.Item Get();
}
```

See a fiddle of this answer at https://dotnetfiddle.net/nBFVLw.

Nested generic types can be counter-intuitive if you're not familiar with using them.

Comment: Imagine, i got the following code that violates a compiler error: `class A<T>
{
    class B<T> : IInterface<T>{ }
}` This means, that the `<T>` of class A gets overriden by `class B<T>` and therefor `IInterface<T>` gets the <T> of class B instead of A, is that correct? Just to understand the logic behind the violation.

Comment: Correct. Inside `B<T>`, `T` is the `T` applied to `B<T>` which can be different to `A<T>`. I've edited my answer to add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Because `A.Item` and `A.Item<T>` are different types and your interface contract is to return Item from `Get` method not `Item<T>`.

In case when you are defining generic classes, you will also need generic interface too, the non-generic interface method contract wouldn't work with a method return generic type,so probably you need to add a generic interface too for the generic  types:

```
public interface  IInterface<T>
{
   A<T>.Item<T> Get<T>();
}
```

### UPDATE:

Your interface contract specified `Get` to return `A<T>.Item<T>` :

```
A<T>.Item<T> Get();
```

while your implementing type `B<T>` only specifies return type to be `Item<T>` :

```
public Item<T> Get()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

due to which compiler is  not allowing  that

As the  interface specified the return type to be `A<T>.Item<T>` so it should be the return type of `Get` method in class `B<T>` too, otherwise it would also complain as ofcourse the `A<T>.Item<T>` and `Item<T>` are different then, so changing the `B<T>` like  following fixes the error:

```
    class B<T> : IInterface<T>
    {
        //
        public A<T>.Item<T> Get<T>()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

You can see the following demo fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/f9Djbz

Comment: you are missing type parameter there in `Get()` , it should be `Get<T>()`

Comment: Somehow, stackoverflow converted my error message, so important pieces got lost. i changed it.

Comment: you would need to give fully qualified return type: `class B<T> : IInterface<T>
        {
            //
            public A<T>.Item<T> Get<T>()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }`

Comment: public A<T>.Item<T> Get() {...} is fixing it, thanks. But why do i have to give the fully qualified return type? In the first example, its enough to say public Item Get() in the Class A, even if the interface method says A.Item Get() ?

Comment: in generics you need to be careful, think about there is another publie `Item<T>` which is not nested  class of  `A<T>` in that both become different types and compiler does not allow that, which is what happening right  now, either remove `A<T>.` from  both interface and class or add either side

Comment: You have violated [compiler warning CS0693](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0693) - see my screenshot of your fiddle [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sqyL.png).